# Salesforce javascript remoting: is it possible from javascript (ie, not visualforce)?

Tags: salesforce

I have a javascript app running in a home page sidebar component. I need to access an apex controller, and javascript remoting would be a good fit, except I can't use VF as I am in a home page component. Is it possible to use javascript remoting from actual raw javascript?

Note - I can't put a VF page in an iframe in the homepage component as I need to access items in the main page.

Comment: You can't do JS remoting without Visualforce, but, assuming you have a session ID, you could call an Apex REST method easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use JAVAScript Remoting without Visualforce page and annotated controller. Instead you can try Web-services, Ajax-toolkit, REST API

Comment: How about an example?  I don't seem able to get the following to work without getting one of those stupid 101 errors.

`
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "/services/apexrest/FeedbackRest?action=popup&config=Default", false); 
xmlHttp.send();
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
`

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting above.  I can't figure out how to get to backticks and newlines showing up where they belong.

Answer (score 1):

You cant access the salesforce context in the HTML or Image type homepage component in any way such as the Ajax-toolkit, REST API suggested above. To use Ajax toolkit you would require a salesforce session id that you cannot get in an html home page component.

The ONLY solution is to use LINK type homepage component. This component allows you to call a method on click. You can access the salesforce context variables in this method, thus get hold of the salesforce sessiod id by calling {!$Api.Session_ID}.

Set this session id in the client session and fetch it in the html Homepage Component and thereon use this id for the ajax toolkit call.